# Validation form - JS

Tags: javascript, html, validation, bootstrap-4

There's comment form using Bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Comments</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="commentForm" name="commentForm" onsubmit="return(validate());">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Leave comment..." rows="3"></textarea><br>
                <button class="btn pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And I wrote a JS validation

```
  <script type="javascript">
  function validate()
  {

     if( commentForm.comments.value == "" )
     {
        alert( "Please leave your comment!" );
        commentForm.comments.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
    </script>
```

it will check if a row is empty, but it doesn't work at all. Help me please, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix type attribute of the script tag to `text/javascript` and add missed `}` of the `validate` function

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve the commentForm element like so :

```js
function validate() {
  // Actually get the DOM element on which you can test value
  var commentForm = document.getElementById('commentForm');
  
  if (commentForm.comments.value === '') {
    window.alert('Please leave your comment!');
    commentForm.comments.focus() ;
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Comments</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="commentForm" name="commentForm" onsubmit="return(validate());">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Leave comment..." rows="3"></textarea><br>
        <button class="btn pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```